# Is it possible to override .objects on a django model?

Tags: python, django, filtering

I'd like to by default only return "published" instances (published=True). Is it possible to override .objects so that MyModel.objects.all() actually returns MyModel.objects.filter(published=True)?

Is this sensible? How would I get the unpublished ones in the rare cases where I did want them?

Answer (score 35):

You can do this by writing a custom [Manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) -- just override the `get_queryset` method and set your `objects` to a Manager instance.  For example:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_queryset().filter(published=True)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # fields
    # ...

    objects = MyModelManager()
```

See the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) for details.  It's sensible if that's going to be your usual, default case.  To get unpublished, create another manager which you can access with something like `MyModel.unpublished_objects`.  Again, the docs have examples on this type of thing.

Comment: Completely right answer. Should be marked as correct @willcritchlow !

Comment: What about update the registers from `MyModel`? When I try to this I receive `object has no attribute 'bulk_update'`